# How to use unix grep and the output together?

Tags: bash, unix, sed, grep, cut

I am new to unix commands. I have a file named server.txt, which has 100 fields, the first line of the file is header.

I want to take a look at the fields at 99 and 100 only.

Field 99 is just some numbers, field 100 is a String.

The delimiter of each field which is a space.

My goal is to extract every tokens in the string(field100) by grep and regex, 
and then output with the field99 with every token extracted from the String,
and skip the first 1000 lines of my records

```
----server.txt--
... ...   ,field99,field100
... ...    5,"hi are"
... ...    3,"how is"

-----output.txt
header1,header2
5,hi
5,are
3,how
3,is
```

so i just have some idea, but i dont know how to combine all the scripts

Here is some of my thought:

```
sed 1000d server.txt cut -f99,100  -d' ' >output.txt
grep | /[A-Za-z]+/|
```

Comment: You might find it easier to use `cut`: http://linux.die.net/man/1/cut

Comment: Your syntax is really weird, by the way.  You want something like `sed 1,1000d server.txt | cut -d, -f99,100 >output.txt; grep -o ',[A-Za-z]*' output.txt` although of course, this still doesn't do what you want.

Comment: If the delimiter is a space then `5,hi` is a single field.  If you are thinking of `5,hi` as being fields 99 and 100, then a space is not your field delimiter.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Sounds more like a job for `awk`.

```
awk -F, 'NR <= 1000 { next; }
  { gsub(/^\"|\"$/, "", $100); split($100, a, / /);
    for (v=1; v<=length(a); ++v) print $99, a[v]; }' server.txt >output.txt
```

The general form of an `awk` program is a sequence of `condition { action }` expressions.  The first line has the condition `NR <= 1000` where `NR` is the current line number.  If the condition is true, the `next` action skips to the next input line.  Otherwise, we fall through to the next expression, which does not have a condition; so, it's uncoditional, for all input lines which reach here.  It first cleans out the double quotes around the 100th field value, and then splits it on spaces into the array `a`.  The `for` loop then loops over this array, printing the 99th field value and the `v`th element of the array, starting with `v=1` and up through the end of the array.

The input file format is sort of cumbersome.  The `gsub` and `split` stuff could be avoided with a slightly more sane input format.  If you are new to `awk`, you should probably go look for a tutorial.

If you only want to learn one scripting language, I would suggest Perl or Python over `awk`, but it depends on your plans and orientation.